# Google Charts API shows blank screen with $(document).ready method

Tags: jquery, google-visualization, jsapi

I've got several functions that instantiate various charts using Google Charts API.

When I call them without jQuery's `$(document).ready` method, everything works fine.  But with that method, I'm looking at blank screen.

Why?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://www.google.com/jsapi" charset="utf-8"></script>
function drawColumnChart1(){..some code..}
function drawColumnChart2(){..some code..}
function drawGeoChart(){.some code..}

//This works fine.
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["piechart", "corechart", "geomap"]});
google.setOnLoadCallback(window.drawColumnChart1);
google.setOnLoadCallback(window.drawColumnChart2);
google.setOnLoadCallback(window.drawGeoChart);



//This doesn't work
$(document).ready(function(){
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["piechart", "corechart", "geomap"]});
    google.setOnLoadCallback(window.drawColumnChart1);
    google.setOnLoadCallback(window.drawColumnChart2);
    google.setOnLoadCallback(window.drawGeoChart);
});
```

**UPDATE**
Here is the error I get in Firebug:

```
uncaught exception: [Exception... "Could not convert JavaScript argument"  nsresult: "0x80570009 (NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS)"  location: "JS frame :: http://www.google.com/jsapi :: Q :: line 20"  data: no]
http://www.google.com/jsapi
Line 22
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[google.setOnLoadCallback with jQuery $(document).ready(), is it OK to mix?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/556406/google-setonloadcallback-with-jquery-document-ready-is-it-ok-to-mix)

is probably the closest answer, and Ryan Wheale's answer on the following may also be helpful.

[Is it ok to use google.setOnLoadCallback multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380043/is-it-ok-to-use-google-setonloadcallback-multiple-times)

Comment: apparently $(document).ready happens before google object is available and that's why  google.load fails inside of $(document).ready or something like that. oh well.

Answer (score 14):

According to the google visualization documentation you need to load the visual package(s) **prior** to onload or jquery ready.  I would suggest loading immediately after the jsapi script reference as shown below.

Otherwise you will get a 1) google is not defined (reference error) or 2) if using ajax possibly a blank response & blank page with no errors.

**load sequence:** (using your example)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.1/jquery.js" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src = "http://www.google.com/jsapi" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["piechart", "corechart", "geomap"]});
</script>

$(document).ready(function(){
    google.setOnLoadCallback(window.drawColumnChart1);
    google.setOnLoadCallback(window.drawColumnChart2);
    google.setOnLoadCallback(window.drawGeoChart);
});
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is the paradigm I am using.  Set a callback for the google.load method, and don't use the google.setOnLoadCallback at all (AFAIK this is not needed).

```
MyChart.prototype.render = function() {
    var self = this;
    google.load("visualization", 
                "1", 
                { callback: function() { self.visualize(); }, 
                  packages: ["corechart"] }
               );
}

MyChart.prototype.visualize = function() {

    var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(
    [
        ['Year', 'Sales', 'Expenses'],  
        ['2004',  1000,      400],
        ['2005',  1170,      460],
        ['2006',  660,       1120],
        ['2007',  1030,      540]   
    ]);

    var options = {
        title: 'Company Performance',
        hAxis: {title: 'Year', titleTextStyle: {color: 'red'}}
    };

    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById("mychart_div"));    
    chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

Comment: This solved my blank page problem, thanks! Instead of calling `google.setOnLoadCallback(callback);` I added `'callback': callback` to the `google.load()` call. Crazy that it works, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

Hi that solution doesn't worked for me, apparently (i'm guessing i'm not sure) google library has some scope issues when you call it inside a jquery object, so the solution is quite simple (although got it wasn't so simple :s) define a global variable and assign the google librari:

```
var localGoogle = google;
```

looks funny huh :)... then use the variable you defined to invoque the setOnCallback, it worked for me i hope it work for you..

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    localGoogle.setOnLoadCallback(window.drawColumnChart1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For an alternate solution you can use 'autoloading' to include the packages you want in the script tag. This negates the need for "google.setOnLoadCallback".

see https://developers.google.com/loader/#AutoLoading for details.

So, you can do everything as you would normally from as jquery document ready event.

There is also a wizard that can set up a URL for you, but currently the link is broken. Here it is anyway: http://code.google.com/apis/loader/autoloader-wizard.html

Answer (score 0):

you hav to call
https://www.google.com/jsapi
instead of
http://www.google.com/jsapi

good luck

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"],   
        callback:function(){drawChart();}});
        //google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
        console.log("enter draw");
              var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
   ['Year', 'value', { role: 'style' } ],
   ['2010', 10, ' color: gray'],
   ['2010', 200, 'color: #76A7FA'],
   ['2020', 16, 'opacity: 0.2'],
   ['2040', 22, 'stroke-color: #703593; stroke-width: 4; fill-color: #C5A5CF'],
   ['2040', 28, 'stroke-color: #871B47; stroke-opacity: 0.6; stroke-width: 8;  
     fill-color: #BC5679; fill-opacity: 0.2']
   ]);
              var view = new google.visualization.DataView(data);

              var options = {
                title: 'Company Performance',
                tooltip: {isHtml: false},
                legend: 'none',
              };

              var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));

              chart.draw(view, options);

        }
```

Demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tehila/uhp37cem/3/)

Answer (score 0):

```
            <!DOCTYPE html>
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript">

            google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
            function drawChart(gtitle,glabel,gwidth,gheight,gtype,gstart,gend,gid) {

                $.ajax({
                        url: "http://localhost/reporte/response.php",
                                type: "GET",
                                dataType: "JSON",
                                cache: false,
                                async: false,
                                data: {start:gstart,end:gend,id:gid},
                                success: function(data) {
                                    var len = 0;
                                    if (data.length)
                                    {
                                    len = data.length;
                                    }

                                    if(len > 0)
                                    {
                                    dataarray = [[gtitle,glabel]];
                                        for (var i = 0; i< len; i++) {
                                            dataarray.push([data[i].label,data[i].value]);
                                        }
                                    }
                                    else if(len==0)
                                    {

                                    }
                                },
                                error:function(data) 
                                {


                                }
                        });

                    var values = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(dataarray);
                    var options = {title: gtitle,width:gwidth,height:gheight};

                            switch(gtype){
                                case 'PieChart':
                                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                                    break;
                                case 'LineChart':
                                    var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                                    break;
                                case 'ColumnChart':
                                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                                    break;
                                case 'AreaChart':
                                    var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('chart'));
                                    break;
                            }

                    chart.draw(values, options);


            }






            $(document).ready(function(){
            //drawChart('Titulo del Grafico','Tickets',800,800,'PieChart',20141001,20141010,'procedure1');
            //drawChart('Titulo del Grafico','Tickets',400,400,'ColumnChart',20141001,20141010,'procedure2');
            //drawChart('Titulo del Grafico','Tickets',400,400,'LineChart',20141001,20141010,'procedure3');
            drawChart('Titulo del Grafico','Tickets',600,400,'AreaChart',20141001,20141010,'procedure4');
            });

            </script>
            </head>
            <body>

            <div id="chart"></div>

            </body>
            </html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try to close the call to `ready`?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    ...
});
^^^
```

Comment: :) thanks. that was just a typo here. it's closed in real code.

Comment: @Andre: Nope, but I'm watching for other answers!  Looks like digitaljoel nailed it.