# google chart is blank after publishing site

Tags: c#, sql-server, charts

I used from google chart in my site , when I debug application in VS everything is ok but when I publish the application the chart is blank ! 
can you please help me in this regards

here is my code :

```
<script src="Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>

<link href="Content/Site.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/googlechart.js"></script>
<%--<script type="text/javascript" src="Scripts/googlechart2.js"></script>--%>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>

<script>
    var chartData; // globar variable for hold chart data
    google.load("visualization", "1", { packages: ["corechart"] });

    // Here We will fill chartData

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $.ajax({
            url: "Main.aspx/GetChartData",
            data: "",
            dataType: "json",
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json; chartset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                chartData = data.d;
            },
            error: function () {
                alert("Error loading data! Please try again.");
            }
        }).done(function () {
            // after complete loading data
            google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
            drawChart();
        });
    });


    function drawChart() {
        var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(chartData);

        var options = {
            title: "Vehicle",
            pointSize: 5
        };

        var lineChart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('chart_div'));
        lineChart.draw(data, options);

    }
</script>
```

back code

```
[WebMethod] 
        [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
        public static object[] GetChartData()
        {
            List<PL_PK> data = new List<PL_PK>();
            //Here MyDatabaseEntities  is our dbContext
            using (PLCPEntities dc = new PLCPEntities())
            {
                data = dc.PL_PK.ToList();
            }

            var chartData = new object[data.Count + 1];
            chartData[0] = new object[]{
                "Time",
                "Total",
                "Plan",
            };

            int j = 0;
            foreach (var i in data)
            {
                j++;
                chartData[j] = new object[] { i.Time.ToString("MMM" + "dd"), i.Total, i.Plan };

            }
            return chartData;
        }
```

Comment: It may helps you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5197547/google-charts-api-shows-blank-screen-with-document-ready-method